# Request to websocket server fails with WebSocket I/O error: Read timed out

Tags: python, websocket, jmeter, fastapi

I have implemented a websocket using fastapi. I am load testing it using Jmeter websocket sampler and some of these requests are failing with WebSocket I/O error: Read timed out (at least this is the error that I get on Jmeter side). The error on server side:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/udit.pandey/Desktop/workspace/chat_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/websockets/websockets_impl.py", line 157, in run_asgi
    result = await self.app(self.scope, self.asgi_receive, self.asgi_send)
  File "/home/udit.pandey/Desktop/workspace/chat_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/udit.pandey/Desktop/workspace/chat_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/udit.pandey/Desktop/workspace/chat_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/udit.pandey/Desktop/workspace/chat_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 146, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/udit.pandey/Desktop/workspace/chat_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 58, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/udit.pandey/Desktop/workspace/chat_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/udit.pandey/Desktop/workspace/chat_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 283, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/udit.pandey/Desktop/workspace/chat_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 57, in app
    await func(session)
  File "/home/udit.pandey/Desktop/workspace/chat_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 247, in app
    await dependant.call(**values)
  File "./websocket.py", line 29, in post_req
    body = await websocket.receive_json()
  File "/home/udit.pandey/Desktop/workspace/chat_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/websockets.py", line 98, in receive_json
self._raise_on_disconnect(message)
  File "/home/udit.pandey/Desktop/workspace/chat_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/websockets.py", line 80, in _raise_on_disconnect
raise WebSocketDisconnect(message["code"])
starlette.websockets.WebSocketDisconnect: 1006
```

There are 2 scenarios that I have covered with this load test:

1. 5 users spawned within 10sec
   Result: No failures.
2. 10 users spawned within 10sec
   Result: Random failures with error "WebSocket I/O error: Read timed out" on Jmeter sampler.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of 1006 and a disconnect error indicates that the server has seen a close of the tcp connection (could be a tcp close or a reset). I guess this close is caused by JMeter closing the connection after the read timeout, but that is pure guessing, as i don't know how your JMeter test-plan is set up.

That you see time outs in JMeter when increasing the number of users could mean that the server cannot handle that load fast enough, i.e. is not able to send responses before the read times out. But it could also mean somewhere else in the chain a resources fails. That's the trouble with load testing: your always testing the whole chain; which each issue you must check whether the issue is in the application-under-test, the test-client or the network. Without more info it is hard to tell what is the problem in your case.